# React compare date

Tags: javascript, reactjs

guys!

I'am trying to do a prize draw website. I want to fix a date and compare to a live date and show the winner.
I'am having a lot of problems when my compare date its equals to my live date, because react dont stop render and call RandomNumber functions a lot of times. I already try to use milliseconds, but sometime react skip it and dont show the winner.

```
import RandomNumber from "components/RandomNumber";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const Datetime = () => {
  const [winner, setWinner] = useState("");
  const [dateState, setDateState] = useState(new Date());

  let timePrize = "10:33:00";
  const datePrize = "12/12/2022";

  console.log(winner);

  useEffect(() => {
    var timer = setInterval(() => setDateState(new Date()), 1000);
    return function cleanup() {
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
  });

  const currentDate = dateState.toLocaleDateString("pt-BR", {
    day: "numeric",
    month: "long",
    year: "numeric",
  });

  const currentTime = dateState.toLocaleString("pt-BR", {
    hour: "numeric",
    minute: "numeric",
    second: "numeric",
    hour12: true,
  });

  if (
    datePrize === dateState.toLocaleDateString() &&
    timePrize === dateState.toLocaleTimeString()
  ) {
    timePrize = "0";
    const winner = RandomNumber();
    setWinner(winner);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <p className="date-custom">{currentDate}</p>
      <p className="time-custom">{currentTime}</p>

      <div>{winner}</div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Datetime;
```

prize draw code:

```
const RandomNumber = () => {
  var items = [
    1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 19, 20, 21, 24, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30,
    31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 49, 50, 56,
  ];
  let item = items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];
  console.log(typeof item);

  const numberToName = (item: number) => {
    if (item === 1) {
      return `Philipe Jensen ${item}`;
    } else if (item === 2) {
      return `Jão  ${item}`;
    } else if (item === 3) {
      return `Xepa ${item}`;
    } else if (
      item === 5 ||
      item === 7 ||
      item === 10 ||
      item === 11 ||
      item === 15 ||
      item === 19 ||
      item === 26 ||
      item === 29 ||
      item === 30 ||
      item === 50
    ) {
      return `Leleo ${item}`;
    } else if (item === 8) {
      return `Felipe ${item}`;
    } else if (item === 9 || item === 21) {
      return `Pimpão ${item}`;
    } else if (item === 12) {
      return `Monteiro ${item}`;
    } else if (item === 13) {
      return `May ${item}`;
    } else if (item === 20) {
      return `Bugs ${item}`;
    } else if (item === 24 || item === 56) {
      return `Vev ${item}`;
    } else if (item === 27) {
      return `Tic ${item}`;
    } else if (item === 28) {
      return `Helo Ams ${item}`;
    } else if (
      item === 31 ||
      item === 32 ||
      item === 33 ||
      item === 34 ||
      item === 35 ||
      item === 36 ||
      item === 37 ||
      item === 38 ||
      item === 39 ||
      item === 40 ||
      item === 41 ||
      item === 42 ||
      item === 43 ||
      item === 44 ||
      item === 45 ||
      item === 46
    ) {
      return `Izumi ${item}`;
    } else if (item === 49) {
      return `Geobanna ${item}`;
    }
  };

  return numberToName(item) || '';
};

export default RandomNumber;
```

I want to compare my timePrize and datePrize variable to a live date and show the winner.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code in your functional component is, as you said, executed on every render. However, the React hook `useCallback` https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback allows you to only execute code when the dependencies of the function change.

For example, see this altered version of your code:

```
  if (
    datePrize === dateState.toLocaleDateString() &&
    timePrize === dateState.toLocaleTimeString()
  ) {
    timePrize = "0";
    const winner = RandomNumber();
    setWinner(winner);
  }

  const isWinner = useCallback(() => {
     if (
        datePrize === dateState.toLocaleDateString() &&
        timePrize === dateState.toLocaleTimeString()
     ) {
       timePrize = "0";
       const winner = RandomNumber();
       setWinner(winner);
     }
  }, [dateState]);

  useEffect(() => isWinner(), [isWinner]);
```

This causes function of "winner" check to only recreate itself when the value of `dateState` changes, which is once (when you create the original state).

This is combined with a `useEffect`, which only runs when *it's own dependencies change*. Given its only dependency is the new `useCallback` function,

Comment: its works!!! Thank you. I need to study more react render.... sorry bother you, but i have other problem... When i update the page, the winner disappear. Is there anyway to fixed it?